# Triangular background for bash PS1 prompt

Tags: bash, prompt, ps1

I am trying to get a triangular background for bash PS1 prompt.
[image: as shown here]

I have tried the existing library called `powerline` but it seems to be heavy for my ageing laptop. I have managed to get the background colour, but have no idea of getting the shape. Currently what I have is:
[image: my PS1].

Is there any straight-forward way of having those shape?

I am using:

```
$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: Are you using one of the [patched fonts](https://github.com/powerline/fonts) for powerline?

Comment: I am not using powerline

Comment: The triangles are, AFAIK, just special characters included in those fonts.

Comment: @chepner: At last I have found the font that are used. Also I tried to dig the powerline sourcecode in github, but failed to get how should I use that font...i.e. how to change the font in PS1. Kindly help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to have powerline patched fonts installed. [Get them here](https://github.com/powerline/fonts)

And you need to configure your terminal to use them. (this ofc depends on your terminal but probably something like settings -> appearance -> fonts)

I've done something similar if you want a startingpoint: [sbp](https://github.com/brujoand/sbp)
You can try it out by running `. prompt.bash`.

Basically all you need if the fonts are installed and enabled is this `$'\uE0B0'` somewhere in your PS1. It's the utf8 code for the fancy triangle. Assuming you're on a recent version of bash with some utf8 as locale, that should do it. Try `echo -e $'\uE0B0'` in your terminal to test it.

Comment: I have installed those fonts, and confirm `echo -e $'uE0B0'` works as intended. But not in my PS1
`PS1="[\u@\h$'\uE0B0' \W]\$ " `

Comment: ah, my bad. You need to evaluate it first. For instance by assigning it first: triangle=$'\uE0B0' and then use $triangle in your PS1. There might be a more elegant way, but this is what I did.

Comment: Hi....one last thing....where I will get those utf8 encoding? like, say, a filled ")"? I tried to search utf8-encoding e.g. http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=57472&number=128, and they are showing different character

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question but if you're looking for the powerline path separator it's $'\uE0B1'. If you're looking for the ) equivalent of the triangle I'm not sure tbh.

Comment: Maybe we could update the answer pointing to https://github.com/brujoand/sbp ?

Comment: I did `sudo apt install fonts-powerline`. Then nothing changed until I opened a new terminal.

Comment: super old thread, but as I still find it through google...

in regards to the fonts... from the sbp webpage:

> Now the hard_to_remember part. Change the settings of your terminal emulator.

you can not just install them, you also have to enable them